# Problems in writing Constructors

Tags: java, oop, constructor, this, super

(first time practice after studying OOP concepts. Go little easy in the answers)

(I am just following instructions from a test-your-skills homework; that's why I am not discussing logics of other classes and files)

I have to add 3 constructors in a single class which is itself extended from a parent class.

First constructor uses the same parameters of the constructor from parent class.

Second and third constructor keep adding parameters respectively.

I am confused about syntax of the body of 2nd and 3rd constructors.

```
public class House 
   extends Building {

// TODO - Put your code here.
private String mOwner;
private boolean mPool;

//This constructor exists in Building class. So, I can use it here with super keyword. Right?
public House(int length, int width, int lotLength, int lotWidth){
    super(length, width, lotLength, lotWidth);
}

//Is using "this" keyword okay here? I am just using the constructor existing in this file.
public House(int length, int width, int lotLength, int lotWidth, String Owner){
    this(length, width, lotLength, lotWidth);
    mOwner = Owner;
}

// Is this right?
public House(int length, int width, int lotLength, int lotWidth, String Owner, boolean pool){
    this(length, width, lotLength, lotWidth, Owner);
    mPool = pool;
}

}
```

Comment: I'd say this is fine, you could also use the same super constructor and add them separately,

Comment: @devgianlu that wouldn't be completely correct design-wise, as it would ignore any *potential* initializations done by the `House` constructor by calling the super constructor directly. In this case it wouldn't matter, but if the least-arg constructor did something different, it would change the behaviour (or you would need to add that to all the constructors).

Comment: Please refine your question's summary and body. It's not clear what exactly you're asking about.
Probably, Builder pattern is the thing you're looking for: https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/

Comment: @Kayaman Can you give an example of that? I am interested in knowing the behaviour of constructors in this case.

Comment: Well, let's say you add `System.out.println("House initialized");` to the first constructor. If you were to call `super()` from other constructors it wouldn't get printed. So the code in the question is correct, and you would not want the other constructors call `super()` and assign all the variables. It would require more writing and be a potential source of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This concept is called constructor chaining

Like the idea is what if we wanted to initialize a building and we didn't know if we wanted it to have a pool yet? If our constructor for this class requires us to enter us a value for boolean pool, we could run into problems.

So constructor chaining is useful because we would still be able to initialize a building without knowing all of the information yet.

we would just use this constructor if we didn't know if we wanted a pool:

```
public House(int length, int width, int lotLength, int lotWidth, String Owner)
```

Everything you wrote is fine. The this() calls are fine.
If you're still unclear -- 
https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-constructor-chaining-with-example/